# React successfully executes a function onClick but not in other parts of this.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function stopRecording() that I'd like to be called when a timer runs out, or when someone presses a stop button. The problem is that when it is called when the timer runs out (the first half of the render function) it is called continuously, despite me bracketing it in an if clause. When it is called as a button event (in the return half of the render function) then it works fine.

Note my console logs. When I open the console in Chrome and let the timer run out, the console logs I marked as successful in my code body runs, but NOT ones that I commented with `//!!!`. I also get the following error continuously: `Invariant Violation: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

```
//...
stopRecording: function() {
    if (this.state.recording){
        console.log("this will log as expected") 
        this.setState({recordingStatus:"",
                        recording:false})
        console.log("this will NOT log as expected'") //!!!
        this.props.emit("recEmit")
    }
}
render: function() {
    var timeBar;
    var countdown = "0";
    var timeBarFill = "#FF9090"
    if (this.state.recording){
        countdown = new Date()-this.state.startTime
        timeBarFill = "#FF3830";
        if (countdown > this.state.maxRecLength){
            console.log('this will log as expected')
            countdown=0
            this.stopRecording()
            console.log('this will NOT log as expected') //!!!

        };
    }
//...
return(
    //...
     <button type="button" id="button" onClick={this.stopRecording}><b>Stop</b></button>
    //...
)
```

Comment: Use the unminified version of React, and post the error message. That'll probably help more than you realize.

Comment: It didn't seem to do anything, but maybe that's because I'm a react n00b. I changed `NODE_ENV `in `package.json`. to = `development` as per the SO thread I linked in my post. Is that correct?


 Example:


```{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --content-base build",
    "deploy": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js",
    "start": "node backend/server.js"
  },...
}```

(also sorry this looks so ugly)

Comment: Update: this wasn't working because I was linking to react.min.js in my webpack.(production.)config files. Now that I am running the full version of React my error message is:

Invariant Violation: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** call setState inside `render()`: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5591#issuecomment-161678219

As render should be a **pure** function of the component's props and state, which means that it should not have any side effects (like changing its own state).

Also, you can't guarantee that React will call your component's `render()` method when your countdown is about to expire. Consider using `setTimeout` in component's life cycle methods.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up solving my issue by handling the timer in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is due to how states work in react. [This article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2893-setstate-state-mutation-operation-may-be-synchronous-in-reactjs.htm) explains it pretty well. I suggest to read it but I can some it up for you:

> setState is usually called asynchronously.
>
> if setState is not triggered by an event that React can keep track of, such as onClick, it is called synchronously.

This means that when you are using onClick everything goes fine because your call of setState in stopRecording does not block and the function finishes before a re render is called. When a timer triggers it this happens synchronously, the state changes and render is called again.

Now, I still do not understand how it can run continuously, since it should have set the state.recording variable to false and I don't see anything that turns it back to true.

Also, be careful to use states just for variables that are truly states: change with time. The maxRecordinLength does not seem to be a state variable, and same for startTime.

EDIT:

after I saw the update I realized that the main issue here is changing a state inside of the render method. I posted [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/martinaglv/3fZT2/) in a comment here but I think it is worth explaining.

Basically, you can solve your issue by calling a setTimer function in the componentDidMount function of react-- more on this [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html).
Something like:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
        setTimer(this.myFunction, this.props.maxRecLength);
},
```

And you myFunction would look like this:

```
myFunction: function(){
        this.setState({timeElapsed: true});
 },
```

Then you can use this.state.timeElapsed in your render function, and whatever is in there will be displayed after the maxRecLength is reached.

Comment: Actually many of those vars are contained as states, which I set as an object as follows: `getInitialState: function(){ return {recording:false,maxRecLength:3000,...}}`. startTime is not a state, but maxRecLength is.

Comment: I understand that, but you should try to keep as states just things that actually change. I doubt that maxRecLength changes over time and causes a re render. also I realize my answer does not solve your specific issue. for that, i would look at this implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/martinaglv/3fZT2/ . Keep in mind how states work though, it will make your life a lot easier!